# Union two or more Objects in vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

using Vuejs/Laravel, i have this code :

```
 var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
   UnionObjects : [],
   persons:[],
  },
```

I have two objects inside persons which are **person.object1** and **person.object2**. I would like to union both those objects in UnionObjets : [],

I use this function:

```
  Union: function(person) {
     this.UnionObjects=person.object1 //here i need to add also person.object2 ;
        },
```

Thank you

Comment: you're still here :), do you want that the two object will be in the same array `unionObjects`?

Comment: Finally Yes .. i came back . Yes exactly ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `concat` function as follows :

```
Union: function(person) {
 this.UnionObjects= person.object1.concat(person.object2 )
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, always here to help. But after union, i got 2 arrays. [0] and [1] , i would like to union also thoses arrays in a single array it is possible ? Second thing missing with push, it's duplicate everytime i execute the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a new array like:

```
this.UnionObjects = [person.object1, person.object2]
```

If UnionObjects already contains elements that you wish to preserve, use a spread operator along with the person objects:

```
this.UnionObjects = [...this.UnionObjects, person.object1, person.object2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I used concat so i could union 2 differents arrays in a single html table